# How to generate a 4-digit numbers with digits from 1 to 6 only?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm looking for a way to generate a 4 digit number with digits from 1 to 6 like 1234, 1251, 3243 ... and so on.

I want it for my `makeDigitsToGuess()` method in my `MastermindDigits` class. Every time a user starts the game, this function should be called and generate a 4 digit number containing only digits from 1 to 6.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
srand(time(0));
cout << "RANDOM NUMBER: " << (rand() % 6 + 1)
                          << (rand() % 6 + 1)
                          << (rand() % 6 + 1)
                          << (rand() % 6 + 1) << endl;
```

this is how far I got on my own. The next step I was thinking about, was to create a `vector` in my method where I could `push_back` those 4x generated random numbers.

Does this make sense? Is there an easier way to code it?

Comment: Please format your code.Thx

Comment: You can generate the final 4-digit integer directly if you build it as x = a*1000 + b*100 + c*10 + d

Comment: Should these numbers be random?

Comment: Yes they should be random

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest this solution using the C++11's `std::uniform_int_distribution`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <iomanip>

int generateFour()
{
    int result=0;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);
    for (int n=0; n<4; ++n)
    {
        result=result*10+dis(gen);
    }
    return result;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4)
              << generateFour() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand much of it so I have to google it up. Never worked with those keywords. Thanks

Comment: This only works by luck. The `pow` function returns a `double`. it would make much more sense to just use `result = result * 10 + dis(gen);`.

Comment: Indeed it would be better with `result=result*10+dis(gen);`. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

You're basically generating a number in base 6, except you replace digit "0" by "6". (Or alternatively add 1 to all). Since it's a 4 digit number, there are 6*6*6*6 possibilities = 1296. So generate a number in the range `[0, 1296)` and print that in base 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned result = 0;
while(!(result / 1000)) /// while "result" doesn't consist of 4 digits
{
    result = result * 10 + rand() % 6 + 1; // multiply previous result by 10, then add new digit.
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: that condition does not work. i.e 5 % 10000 is 5. That prints only one digit.

Comment: yea, my bad, fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
const unsigned sup(6 * 6 * 6 * 6);

unsigned base6[sup];

for (unsigned i(0); i < sup; ++i)
{
  base6[i] = (i / 216 % 6) * 1000 +
             (i /  36 % 6) *  100 +
             (i /   6 % 6) *   10 +
                            i % 6;
}
```

then your random number is `base6[rand() % sup]`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make this easy, practically as you did in question.

```
std::string number;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  number += rand() % 6 + 1;
}
std::cout << std::stoi(number);
```

I didn't test this code, but its the basic idea. You put everything into a string and convert it to a number. Perhaps not the best idea, but at least better than doing 4 times `rand()` :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the same task as me (PAD2) so i can help you. 
This is my function makeDigitsToGuess:

```
int randomNumber = 0;
int x = 3; //Numbers to guess
for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
    randomNumber = rand() % 6 + 1;
    digits[i] = randomNumber;

}
```

This gives me a four digit number for the play mode.